# Error message affects the height of the text field - helperText material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, textfield, react-hook-form

I have a react hook form. After validation, the error message make my text field moves up.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzgjC.png)

Here is how helperText setup:

```
<TextField
      helperText={invalid && error}
/>
```

After validation, the error message will appears with the help of helperText. Then the textField will be shift up.
Is there any way I can make the error message does not affect the height of the textField?

I am really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this by setting a default value of " " (A text that has only space typed in it) to your helperText in the  component. This way the height is already allocated for the text and will remains the same whether there is an error or not.